# Unable to Output XML using XSLT in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

i am trying to output the Form using XML & XSLT in php but i am unable to fullfill the condition somehow.here is what my XML look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="form.xsl"?>

<root>

    <formset>
            <field>
                <type>text</type>                
                <value>This is test value</value>
            </field>
            <field>
                <type>radio</type>                
                <value>Male</value>
            </field>
            <field>
                <type>checkbox</type>                
                <value>Hobby</value>
            </field>
            <field>
                <type>button</type>                
                <value>Click Me</value>
            </field>                                    
    </formset>

</root>
```

and Here is my XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Rendering of Form</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <xsl:for-each select="/root/formset/field">

                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="type = text">
                                <input type="text" value="{value}" />
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="type = radio">
                                <input type="radio" value="{value}" /> <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="type = checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="{value}" /> <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="type = button">
                                <input type="button" value="{value}" />
                            </xsl:when>                
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                             <span>Unknown Type</span>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>             

                    </xsl:for-each>

                </form>



            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

my PHP code is this simple echo the output:

```
<?php

// LOAD XML FILE
$XML = new DOMDocument();

$XML->load('form.xml');

// START XSLT
$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$XSL = new DOMDocument();

$XSL->load('form.xsl');
$xslt->importStylesheet( $XSL );
echo $xslt->transformToXML( $XML );

?>
```

but somehow my output renders `xsl:otherwise` condition can anyone tell me why ?? i am new to XSLT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not actually to do with PHP, but simply to do with the fact you have missed out some apostrophes in your xsl:when test statements. You are currently doing this

```
 <xsl:when test="type = text">
```

But this is comparing an element called **type** against an element called **text**, which doesn't actually exist in your XML. You need to do this instead

```
 <xsl:when test="type = 'text'">
```

i.e. You need to compare against a literal string, enclosed in apostrophes.

If you are keen to learn XSLT, here is a way to do the same thing without the need for **xsl:for-each** of **xsl:choose**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="html"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <head>
            <title>Rendering of Form</title>
         </head>
         <body>
            <form action="" method="post">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="root/formset/field"/>
            </form>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="field">
      <input type="{type}" value="{value}"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="field[type != 'text'][type != 'radio'][type != 'checkbox'][type != 'button']">
      <xsl:text>Unknown Type</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using templates in this way is usually preferred as it helps re-use code, and cuts down on indentation to make it more readable. Note that the more specific template will always get chosen first when matching elements.

Comment: Great Thanks a bunch mate working now. Just a quick question do i need these apostrophes even if have to compare some number value??!!

Comment: Nope. If you are comparing against a number, you don't need apostrophes.

Comment: Wow! Lovely Thanks for telling me the smart way to achieve the same thing yep i surely am interested in learning XSLT thats why trying the things in it